# How to prove a rectangle is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Show that the rectangle $K=[0,a]\times [0,b]$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

My try :
Take some open cover $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in \Lambda}$ of $K$. Now I tried to prove it is closed and bounded. Now if we take any point $x\in K$ we have $\|x-x_0\|\le a+b$. Here $x_0$ is the centre of $K$. So it is bounded. Now take a point $x\notin K$ to be a limit point of $K$. Now here I am stuck. I don't reach any contradiction from it. How to proceed? Or maybe we should try another way? Like proving every sequence in $K$ has a convergent sub sequence, or something like that?

Comment: If you are going to use the fact that the rectangle is closed and bounded, you certainly do not need to take any open cover!

Comment: You should **really** try to prove the set is closed (I hope no one tells you how to do this for at least a day...)

Comment: You could try showing that $K^c$ is open. If $x \not\in K$, you can say something about one of the components...